# About a query and subquery

Tags: mysql

this is my query, and I already know the problem but I dont have an idea about how to solve it:

```
$queryString = "SELECT * FROM `users_list` "WHERE `user_id` like (SELECT `user_id` FROM `equipments_list` WHERE  `equipment_mac` like '%$searchStringMacRevised%')"
```

So, this is the error sometimes I get:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

I see that the problem is that if the mac address is registered more than once, it will give me more than one user ID, and when we are going to select the information, I have too much user id to generate the table. Can you guys help me to see how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are just comparing to the user id directly, you could use an `IN` clause, such as

```
SELECT * FROM users_list
WHERE user_id IN 
    (SELECT user_id FROM equipments_list
     WHERE  equipment_mac like '%$searchStringMacRevised%')
```

This would allow you to potentially compare to multiple user ids.

If we want only 1 user id, then you may need to use the `LIMIT` type of query suggested in other answers.

Comment: It works, but it only gives me the first record. How can I get it to give me all the records?

Answer (score 0):

It means that your `inner select` is returning **more than one** row , it should exactly return 1 row in order to match record for outer query

```
   $queryString = "SELECT * FROM `users_list` "WHERE `user_id` like (SELECT `user_id` FROM `equipments_list` WHERE  `equipment_mac` like '%$searchStringMacRevised%' LIMIT 1)"
```

Comment: It works, but it only gives me the first record. How can I get it to give me all the records?